# When iPhone Application Submitted Information Changes Reflects

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Fortunately our first application is in App Store now..

And in my itunesconnect account some of the fields are editable like screenshots, support url etc..

So, my question is if I update some of my screenshots or if I update the support url field when it will be reflects to itunes ?

Or it will directly reflects once I update my current application ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is a question about Apple's iTunes Connect website, which is outside of the scope of this site.

Comment: @Brad Larson Thanks for pointing out my mistake... But I have found lots of similar question in stackoverflow regarding whole process of iPhone Application Submission to Approval. Still if you feel that it's not worth to be here, then I can remove it...

Comment: Many others have been closed and deleted.  We don't always catch everything that's asked.  Most of the ones that are left had some programming aspect to them, such as proper build settings or questions about whether specific application features are acceptable in a distributed product.  Sorry for the harsh tone, but I'd like to keep the site focused on programming-related questions and leave the rest for https://devforums.apple.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those will be reflected soon (from half-an-hour to a day).